# WiFi problem with Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: networking, 20.04, wireless, reboot

I have a problem with the WiFi oof my laptop.

When I start the computer with this SO (Desktop Version 20.04 LTS), I select a WiFi network and I connect to it.
When I reboot (or shutdown and restart the PC), this WiFi network is still available between the known networks, but I cannot connect to it. It shows the wifi symbol with the "?" on it.
This issue happens with every WiFi networks.
If before shutdown/restart the PC the WiFi network is removed from the known ones, at the next restart I can connect to it.
But later the issue appears again.

Someone knows how to solve this issue? Or someone has some advices?

Thank you!

Edit: this is the output that I get with sudo dmesg | grep

[sudo dmesg grep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKQBk.png)

Edit: second output
[ls -al /etc/resolv.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPOBw.png)

Edit: third output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f6if.png)

Comment: The `?` means that you are connected to the router but not connected to the internet. To start the diagnosis, check the message log. First, find out your wireless interface with the command: `iwconfig`. It should be something like wlp3s0 or wlo1 or similar. Next, search the log for that interface: `sudo dmesg | grep wlp3s0` or whatever you found. As the output may be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi, thank you and sorry for the delay. I edited the post with the output I got.

Comment: Looks perfect so far. Now may we see as an edit: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: I have just posted the second output

Comment: Still looks perfect. When you try and fail to connect, getting the `?`, please run: `sudo journalctl -fu NetworkManager` and paste it as above. Is the router set to auto channel select or a fixed channel? Please try fixed.

Comment: I pasted the output. I tried with three different network. 1 fixed (my home router), 1 auto (my home repeater, the one now in the picture, at least I think it is auto) and the hotspot of my phone (no idea if it is fixed or not). I always got the same issue. Docker is the first software I installed after the VPN client but I already try to reinstall it without changes. And obviously, the VPN is off at the start of the PC.

Comment: I know very little about VPN but I believe that it takes over DNS resolution and I suspect it doesn't do it gracefully. I have no other suggestions. Sorry.